# GLIBCXX not found from within gdb

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I try to debug a program with gdb and after the run-command I get the error (within gdb)

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found
```

I made sure that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set, i.e. `set env LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, as it is in the calling shell from where, if starting the program this error message does not appear.

Is this error due to not installed debug versions of libc++?

Comment: When exactly do you get this message? When starting gdb, or when starting your program within gdb?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this error due to not installed debug versions of libc++

No.

You are not using `libc++`, you are using `libstdc++`, which is entirely different. The problem doesn't have anything to do with debug versions of `libstdc++` either.

The problem is two-fold:

1. You are building your binary with a newer version of GCC than what is installed on your system, in such a way that requires you to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
2. You have `~/.bashrc` or `~/.cshrc` or `~/.zshrc` which *resets* `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This prevents GDB from running your binary, because gdb `run` command actually does `$SHELL /path/to/binary <args>`, and since your shell resets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, by the time your binary runs, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is already incorrect.

It is generally best to build your binary such that it doesn't require setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the first place. This is achieved by adding `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/directory-containing-correct-libstdc++.so.6` to your link line.

This solves problem #1, and would allow you to debug the binary with GDB.

You should also change your `~/.bashrc` such that it doesn't do anything for non-interactive shells. This [document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html) shows how to achieve that.